# Как сделать реверс строки без использования стандартных методов?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как сделать реверс строки без использования стандартных методов к примеру reverse() и т. д. Также не нужно использовать массив, дополнительные переменные. Нужно просто на месте менять значение строки

К примеру здесь используется дополнительная переменная o;

```
function reverse(s) {
  var o = '';
  for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    o += s[i];
  return o;
}
```

Ниже не используется дополнительная переменная, но такое решение не подходит, так как строка просто увеличивается в два раза, а потом уменьшается.

```
function reverse(s) {
  for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    s+= s[i];
    }
  return s.substring(s.length/2);
}
```

Может есть другой способ это сделать ? К примеру менять первый и последний символ и так дальше пока не поменяется все. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Непонятно, что именно нельзя использовать...

Comment: В цикле обменивайте местами прямо в строке байты с позициями `i` и `s.length-i+1`. Чтобы не использовать дополнительных переменных при обмене, временно добавьте к исходной строке ещё один символ и используйте его как буфер, потом отрежете... или используйте любые методы байт-обмена in-place (скажем, троекратный XOR).

Comment: Если вам дам исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Рекурсией:

```
function reverse(s) {
    if (s === "")
        return "";   
    else
        return reverse(s.substr(1)) + s.charAt(0);
}
```

Или ES6(формально, без доп. переменных):

```
function reverse(s) {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(s, (result, c) => c + result, "");
}
```